# Not able to check if user is logged in magento system in footer.phtml file on some pages

Tags: magento

I am not able to check if user is logged in or not in magento system. I need to check it in footer.phtml file and show the footer links accordingly. It is working in some of the pages but not in all pages. when i gone inside in the issue and printed session array it is not accessible in some pages and in other pages it is accessible.

I used below code to check if user is logged in the system or not.

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
and 
$this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()
```

But it return false in some pages but works in others.

and also when i gone inside the footer and printed the current action and module name.
it is showing module customer and action create where as address bar shows customer/somethingelse.

I am very surprised.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Including which pages/URL don't work would help people answer your question.

Comment: Works in all the magento core pages but not in custom pages that I have created in magento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Footers are cached blocks which exempts them from session data. You will need to either disable the HTML blocks cache completely or modify Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer so it is not individually cached.